# Why date is not updated in Linux Shell Script?

Tags: linux, shell, date, cron

I created a shell script to create cron to clean ram cache in every 5 minutes and log when it cron workes into log file cron_test. My script is below. However, date stamp remains when I fisrt run this script, it is not updated ! For instance if I run below script in time Mon 01 Feb 2021 11:47:55 PM, then it contionously write "clean_ram worked @ Mon 01 Feb 2021 11:47:55 PM EST" at each line! How can I update date to when cron successfuly worked ?

```
    #!/bin/sh
    
    cat  <<EOF1 > /home/clean_ram.sh
    #!/bin/sh
    exec sudo -s <<'EOF'
    sync; echo 1>/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches # clean ram cache
    echo "clean_ram worked @ `date`" >> /home/cron_test
    EOF1

    echo "EOF" >> /home/knoppix/clean_ram.sh # add EOF to the end of clean_ram.sh file manually

    # make it exevutable 
    chmod a+x /home/knoppix/clean_ram.sh

    echo "[IS4] creat cron list in crontab"
    (crontab -l; echo "*/5 * * * * /home/clean_ram.sh"| crontab -
```

Comment: Have you considered opening `/home/clean_ram.sh` in a text editor and seeing why it's behaving the way it is?

Comment: Use `cat << 'EOF1' > /home/clean_ram.sh`  That is, use a non-interpolating heredoc

Comment: Actually yes.I have already opened it an what I saw is what I exaclty wrote including EOF lines. Is that the EOF is the problem? Did you point out that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an interpolating heredoc, so

```
`date`
```

is being interpolated when the heredoc expands.  Just quote the delimiter to prevent that.  Also, it's not 1992.  Use `$()`:

```
cat  << 'EOF1' > /home/clean_ram.sh
#!/bin/sh
exec sudo -s <<'EOF'
sync; echo 1>/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches # clean ram cache
echo "clean_ram worked @ $(date)" >> /home/cron_test
EOF1
```